# Web Extensibility

Tags: qtp, web-extensibility

I am working with QTP now for some time and heard of web extensibility, I have tried to do a lot of research on this topic but to no avail. Can please through some light on this topic and small demo for this. What all are the prerequisite for working on Web Extensibility. I need to explore on this topic further to get a hold on it and use within my project.

thanks a lot in anticipation..

Answer (score 0):

The prerequisites for QTP web extensibility are QTP 9.5 or later (with IE) and you can find a tutorial on the installation DVD under the extensibilities sub-menu.

You can find a (not very flattering) description of implementing an extensibility in the [advanced QTP blog](http://www.advancedqtp.com/DemoMTW/content/tech.web_ext.html).

If you're using QTP 10 then a [Web2.0 feature pack has been released](http://support.openview.hp.com/selfsolve/document/KM771788) which includes a tool called [Extensibility Accelerator](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Dttt_P1D4EU) which makes it much easier to create a web extensibility project.

Good luck.