# quick test pro 10.0 javascript control?

Tags: qtp

is there any plugin that will work with javascript controls like slidebars and dropdown lists? My qtp recognize only them as WebElement and if i wanna select something from dropdownlist i simply can't.
The javascript framework is Prototype JavaScript framework.

Answer (score 0):

QTP doesn't support [prototypejs](http://prototypejs.org/) out of the box. However you can create a Web-Extensibility project to support specific controls (if you do please share with the rest of the community).

You can find a bit of information on how to get started [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/917214/web-extensibility).